# Mesh edge detection for a climbing system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm working on a VR game, which has some climbing mechanics in it. The player will be able to grab onto edges and I want to use dynamic edge detection instead of what I'm doing right now, which is placing colliders on the edges that I want the player to be able to grab. Doing this takes a long time, and doesn't allow for any procedural mesh generation.

I know that something like this can be achived with shaders, but since they don't return any data, thats not an option. Are there any other ways I could do it? Even a way to mark the edges in the mesh instead of using colliders would be great.

Comment: Could you possibly use `Mesh.bounds` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html then in the Editor select the edges that you want to be climbable?

Comment: @jiveturkey I don't understand how mesh.bounds help here. It's just a box around the actual model.

Comment: You are trying to determine the edges of your mesh?

Comment: Yes, and I want to be able to manage them, for example use the ones that are horizontal.

Comment: You want *ad hoc* identification, at runtime, of climbable edges? No setup work at build time? How regular is your world geometry (eg, Minecraft-esque or more realistic/irregular 3D)?

Comment: @hacksalot It can be preprcessed, but it would be nice if I could do it at runtime. The geometry is pretty blocky since it's an urban environment with a lot of straight lines.

Comment: Well, now you've got your all edges, what do you consider a "climbable" edge?  Closest to the top of the far camera culling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. This is an opinionated take, not necessarily a best practice. Your mileage may vary.

1. Forget colliders unless your levels are small. They're too expensive here. I like to use colliders for *classic physics rigidbody collisions*. I don't find they're always the best match for motive interactions like walking or climbing etc, esp. in Unity, and often using a collider to detect a simple line-plane intersection is overkill.
2. Analyze your mesh (at runtime, say, during level load) and pull out grabbable edges/faces. [Here's one way to do it](https://answers.unity.com/questions/566779/how-to-find-the-vertices-of-each-edge-on-mesh.html). These will be navigation waypoints for your climb. Note that you have to define what constitutes a "grabbable" edge or face, which to me would mostly depend on the face orientation, which you can get from the face normal.
3. If your levels are large or complex, further group those faces into a volume tree structure (oct-tree, k-d, something to help you locate edges in the vicinity).
4. As the player climbs, test for intersections between the player's hand and nearby climbable faces. You may be able to rely on the player's actions here and perform your most time-consuming tests only when he "clutches" what he believes to be a climbable edge.

Under this system, climbing is essentially a mini-platformer. The hand must "jump" from one platform to another platform, enabling further vertical movement.

Comment: By "grabbable" I mean anything that is similar to a ledge, where one face is flat and the other is at an angle (ideally I could define the angle range). Do you know any algorithms that could help me find edges like that? I think I think I can figure it out myself, but it would be nice to know if somebody has already done it.

Comment: In the simplest case, two faces adjoining along an edge, you can get the orientation of each face from the face normal and compare. In the most complex case -- an irregular in 3 dimensions concave or convex piece of real-world grabbable geometry, a collider might be your best best in spite of what I said above, due to the algorithmic complexity of arbitrary 3D shape detection. But I'd create the collider on demand, if possible, as the avatar nears or attempts to grab the geometry. Optimal solution will hinge on your "special knowledge" of the world geometry.

Comment: For ex, if you, as the world creator, know that *all* grabbable edges will have an upward-pointing face (normal (0,1,0)) and perpendicular outward-pointing face normal, that simplifies the problem. Or if you know you need irregular geometry, maybe you accept a range of normals as all pointing roughly "upward", allowing your real-world geometry to carry slight bevels and slopes etc. You can also used a mixed approach: line-plane intersections for "clean edges" and colliders for the funky geometry.